# What is Riddick's middle name?

Tags: riddick-franchise

In *Pitch Black* and its sequels (*Chronicles of Riddick* and *Riddick*), Riddick is introduced as "Richard **B.** Riddick".

**What does the "B" stand for?**

Comment: "Broderick" maybe?

Comment: Some websites suggest "Badass".

Comment: "Be" ?

https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-78affa95ef04c31b67cf169edda1539c

Comment: Plot twist: Richard Beetlejuice Riddick

Comment: Barbarella would be an option

Comment: Richard "Buffy" Riddick?

Comment: Richard "Bee" Riddick?

Comment: Bob................

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### We don't know.

It has never been revealed.

Just a small piece of trivia: You say he is introduced as "Richard B. Riddick" in all three films, but his first name and initial are not mentioned in the second film, *Chronicles of Riddick*. That's all I got.